# Почему не отправляются письма с SMTP?

Tags: php, email, smtp, symfony

На странице сайта есть форма для отправки письма клиенту. Письмо отправляет PHP с помощью SMTP службы через Symfony Swift Mailer. Сервер smtp.gmail.com, порт 465, опция SSL включена. Часть писем не доходит адресатам. Не удалось выявить условия при которых 
случается эта ошибка. В чем может быть дело?

Comment: в первую очередь стоит узнавать подробности на сайте gmail.com.

Comment: Попробуйте вести лог ответом smtp гугла. Тут подробно его ошибки расписаны https://support.google.com/a/answer/3726730?hl=ru

Comment: у Яндекса аналогичная фича есть, в чем прелесть гугла???

Answer (score 4):

Отправлять письма через smtp gmail плохая идея. Google в любое время и без предупреждения может блокировать отправку почты, например, при превышении лимитов отправки. А то и вовсе может запросто заблокировать Вашу почту за спам. Узнать обычно можно в логах, в папке app/logs/prod.log. Там будет написано что то типа, "невозможно отправить почту, ошибка smtp сервера...", это означает что Google заблокировал отправку.

В данном случае, рекомендую настроить отправку писем через свой сервер или надо заходить сюда https://accounts.google.com/UnlockCaptcha, чтобы разблокировать почту (не всегда помогает). Еще как вариант помогает почему то смена пароля в приложении, которое должно быть забито у вас в почте.

Отправку через Gmail как правило используют во время разработки, когда надо отправить 2-3 письма.