# SwiftMailer, долго отправляет сообщения

Tags: php, yii2

Yii2 фреймворк. Нужно сделать рассылку по определенных e-mail. Их может много, допустим 20 штук. Делаю отправку в методе сохранения модели.

Отправляю согласно документации

```
public static function sendMultipleMail($options, $setFrom, $setSubject, $setTextBody)
    {
        $messages = [];
        foreach ($options as $option) {
            $messages[] = \Yii::$app->mail->compose()
                ->setFrom([$setFrom])
                ->setTo($option->user->email)
                ->setSubject($setSubject)
                ->setTextBody($setTextBody);
        }
        Yii::$app->mail->sendMultiple($messages);
        return true;
    }
```

Конфиг

```
'mail' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'viewPath' => '@backend/mail',
            'useFileTransport' => false,//set this property to false to send mails to real email addresses
            //comment the following array to send mail using php's mail function
            'transport' => [
                'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
                'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
                'username' => '*******',//need username
                'password' => '*****',//need password
                'port' => '587',
                'encryption' => 'tls',
            ],
        ],
```

Проверял на 20 почтовых адресов - пока все письма будут отправлены, тогда сохранится модель . Когда 20шт - время сохранения - примерно 25 сек.
Вот такие логи . 1,2 - вот такие блоки отправки . Думаю проблема в том, что каждый раз при отправке соединение устанавливается, после отправки прерывается

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос, можно ли каким-то способом оптимизировать отправку??Или каким образом тогда отправлять сообщения, если не в модели сохранения...? Чтобы не было такой задержки??

Comment: Возможно, gmail при приеме писем делает всякие проверки, поэтому прием писем происходит не очень быстро. А почему вы отправляете напрямую через gmail? На вашем сервере нем почтовика? Через локальный почтовый сервер было бы быстрее.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/443213/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81-smtp

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете отправлять почту в отдельном потоке. Для этого код отправки почты  вы можете перенести в консольную команду, и при сохранении в модели запускать эту команду через специальный компонент.
Пример:

- установите через composer [symfony/process](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html)
- при сохранении модели запустите эту команду

  ```
  $process = new Process(Yii::getAlias('@app/') . 'yii send-mail ,'> /dev/null 2>&1');

  $process->start();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема не в том, какой программой вы отправляете сообщения, а в том, через какой сервис вы это делаете. Если будете отправлять не через GMail, а через локальный почтовый демон, то всё будет работать моментально.

```
'transport' => [
    'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'port' => '25',
],
```

Либо, для ещё более быстрой отправки, используйте `Swift_SendmailTransport` без настроек. В этом случае отправка письма сводится к записи тела письма в файл на диске в очереди почтового сервера, что без сомнений много быстрее чем установка TLS соединения с удалённым сервером где-то в далёкой Калифорнии.

Answer (score 0):

Кстати метод `setTo` может принимать массив адресов. Так что не надо никакого цикла и `sendMultiple`. Возможно так как раз будет быстрее!